# Is that possible to create multiple test scenarios?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I'm looking for a solution to create different test scenarios. I have a e2e test now. Its testing navigation and components on pages. I want create another one to test create/edit/delete and see if that methods works. Maybe something starts when i write `ng e2e test-scenerio2` to the console or an different way. I'm waiting for your answers. Thank you for reading.

Edit;
I know i could create different test like that;

```
describe('Test 2', () => {
  ...
});
```

But it's processing all time. I want to do that only when i want to test this section without transform it to comment lines.

**Solution;**

1. Created an .ts file in the e2e/src folder (i named `app.apitest-spec.ts`).
2. on protractor.conf.js file create an suites object if doesn't exists

   ```
   suites:{
    pagesTest: './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts',
    apiTest: './src/**/*.apitest-spec.ts'
   },
   ```
3. on cmd run suite like that ;

   ng e2e --suite=apiTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. If I've understood it correctly, you want to run specific tests and not all of them;
There are several ways to accomplish this.

*In tests:* 
Adding f before `describe` (`fdescribe`) or `it` will let you run only that `describe`/`it`; 
Adding x means to skip that `describe`/`it`.

*Suites:*
in your config file, define suits like:

```
exports.config = {
  ...
  suites: {
    suite1: 'fileRoute/name.ts'
    suite2: 'fileRoute/name2.ts'
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

and then run a specific suite with

```
protractor configFile.js --suite name
```

You can combine usage of suites, f and x

Hope it helps (providing this is what you've meant in your question)

Comment: yes, this is what i mean. I will try it and then confirm as answer. thank you